# Placing RadListView inside Grid Solves iOS Scroll issue but breaks on Android

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, mobile, telerik

I am using Xamarin Forms (2.5.1) with Telerik Data Controls (2018.1.405.2) to develop an app for iOS and Android. I am targeting iOS 11.4 and Android 7.0.

I have a RadListView for displaying a list of items that makes use of the common "pull down to refresh, scroll down to automatically query more entries" workflow. That functionality works. On Android I can scroll all the way to the bottom and see the last entry in the list without any issues.

On iOS, the last four elements in the list are always cut off. Manually pulling down against the auto-snap-back allows peaking at the cut off items, but obviously this is not desired functionality. On the Telerik forum I found a thread that addresses this issue here:

https://www.telerik.com/forums/last-cell-of-listview-cutoff

Placing the RadListView inside of a Grid element as mentioned in the last post in that thread does indeed fix the problem on iOS. I am then able to scroll to the bottom of the list and see the last elements without fighting the auto-snap-back.

```
<Grid Padding="0, 0, 0, 0">
    <td:RadListView x:Name="MyListView" ... >
```

However this seems to break things on Android. On Android, the RadListView just disappears entirely when I do this. None of its elements draw.

I've tried various things such as specifying a single column and row, both with Auto size and set sizes of values between 1 and 1000, (and placing the RadListView in Row 0 and Column 0) but that doesn't change anything.

My current thinking is that I am going to need to detect that the platform is iOS and add a fix in the .xaml.cs to re-parent the RadListView under a new Grid element which I create programmatically. I haven't gotten that to work quite right yet, but I think it should be possible with something like the following called from the view's constructor:

```
private void AddGridParent()
{
    var grid = new Grid();
    grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto });
    grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Auto });
    grid.Padding = new Thickness(0.0);
    grid.Parent = MyListView.Parent;
    grid.Children.Add(MyListView, 0, 0);
}
```

..But that doesn't seem like it should be necessary. I'm not trying to do  anything unusual. I have done some extensive searching and I can't find any known issues with putting a RadListView inside of a Grid on Android.

My question is, what is causing the RadListView not to show up on Android when placed inside of a Grid and is there a standard, accepted fix for this issue?

Edit: I'll also note that I dislike the black-box nature of the Grid parent solution to begin with and am trying to figure out why it works on iOS.